# Inserting ArrayList fields into DB at once

Tags: java, database

Is it possible to insert arraylist into database at once or do I have to iterate through every record and insert one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do batch insertions using JDBC:

```
PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (?, ?)");
for(MyElement e : myList) {
    ps.setString(1, e.getString());
    ps.setInt(2, e.getInt());
    ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
```

Comment: I do the same thing but with execute update instead addBatch, would you mind telling me the difference and then I mark it as answer? Also if you dont mind - What is faster, if you consider doing it with 5 milion records?

Comment: The difference is with ``executeBatch``, only one call containing all the inserts is made to the DB while when calling ``executeUpdate`` in the loop, as many calls as the size of your list are made to the DB. Since a call to the DB is what takes the longest time here, the first solution using ``executeBatch`` is definitely faster.

Comment: One last thing, cannot the Batch be overloaded by that many records?

Comment: It might happen if your list is really large. In that case you might call ``ps.executeBatch()`` in the loop every (say) 10 million records.

Comment: If I could, I would give you more likes, thanks :), I have tested it and in 1000 records it is 5 times faster with the batch.

Answer (score 1):

you can insert into database at once with batchquery like

```
int i =0;
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DataTable VALUES (?)");
while(i<list.size()){
ps.setInt(1,list.get(i));
ps.addBatch();
i++;
}
ps.executeBatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `ArrayList to Array` and then pass array to the `PrepareStatement` using `setArray()` method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray%28int,%20java.sql.Array%29